# WPF Auto height in code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How could I set the value of the `Height` property of a WPF control in C# code to "`Auto`"?

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

I want to reproduce this behavior in the code behind. Any ideas?

Answer (score 170, accepted):

Perhaps [this link](http://msmvps.com/blogs/kevinmcneish/archive/2010/03/03/wpf-setting-the-height-or-width-to-auto-in-code.aspx) will help you.

> At times, you may want to
> programmatically set the Height or
> Width of a WPF element to Auto in
> code. To do this, just use the
> Double.NaN (Not a Number) value.
>
> For example, in C#:
>
> this.txtName.Width = Double.NaN;

Comment: Don't work in my case. But i am changing height width through behaviors (expression blend 4.0 lib)

Comment: Link is dead but you can access a archived version [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20131203203321/http://msmvps.com/blogs/kevinmcneish/archive/2010/03/03/wpf-setting-the-height-or-width-to-auto-in-code.aspx)

Comment: Nimrod's answer is much more explicit and easier to understand.

Comment: Getting 'NaN' is not a valid value for property 'MaxWidth'

Comment: I feel Nimrod's answer is the cleanest and should now be the accepted answer (not sure of `GridLength.Auto` was possible in the past). There's also `GridLength.Star` to fill remaining area.

Comment: @WolfgangSchreurs but this appears to be a more general answer. The other one won't work in cases where Height is actually just a double.

Comment: The important part is: 1) it involves only dimensions that are doubles (e.g. TextBox's `Width`) and not of type `GridLength` like in this case, 2) when you bind said `Width` to some DependencyProperty you have to provide `double.NaN` as `PropertyMetadata` in the `Register()` call to achieve the default behavior of control getting an actual width unless specified. If you don't pass it, your `Width` will always be zero if not explicitly set, which can lead to some funny moments with your app

Comment: This does not work for me.

Answer (score 120):

You can use

```
RowDefinition rd = new RowDefinition();  
rd.Height = GridLength.Auto;  
ContentGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rd);
```

Comment: Any differences between this answer and the accepted answer? Because if not, this should be the top answer for not circumventing the framework.

Comment: According to reflector, GridLength.Auto is 
    new GridLength(1.0, GridUnitType.Auto); therefore not exactly equivalent to accepted answer, but much more readable.

Comment: This is not as general a solution as the accepted answer. Not all controls implement a Height property as a 'GridLength' object (struct). For those that just use double this answer does not work. And the question was not asking generally, it only used a grid as an example.

Answer (score 4):

While the question has been answered with the code-behind (as asked), here is the same solution in XAML for basic control properties who don't have `"auto"`:

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"

Height="{x:Static sys:Double.NaN}"
```

Posting because google took me here when searching for XAML solution for a `TextBox` (auto doesn't exist).