# Change Auto Width at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a XAML/WPF custom control that is used to display a list of items.  I initially set this controls Width to Auto as I want it to rezize to the width of the widest item added to it.

```
<custom:MyCustomControl ThemeName="MyDefaultTHeme" 
                        x:Name="PART_MyItems" 
                        Height="Auto" 
                        Width="Auto"/>
```

However, during runtime the user can change the ControlTemplate (ThemeName) of my custom control which changes how the items look (Icon and text size etc). The control will then change its width according to the width of the items and can sometimes fill up the entire width of the screen. This I do not want.

How can I either, turn off `Width="Auto"` after the first use (First load of control) or set the width to the initial width and not change it again>

Comment: Why not set a MaxWidth to constrain it getting larger than you want?

Comment: this may work for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459089/wpf-auto-height-in-code

Answer (score 2):

Just call `MyCustomControl.Width = MyCustomControl.ActualWidth` before you change its theme, since you probably have C# code doing the theme switch.  That will get rid of the `Auto`.

Comment: This works and does not resize my control.  BUt now when I drag a GridSlitter to the left my control stays the same size and does not expand with the GridSplitter.  So its a littke more awkward than I first explained.  I would like the AutoSize to be turned off when the theme is changed and then back on again afterwards if that makes sense

Comment: If you can't do a multibinding on Width taking into account all your sizing factors from the surrounding control states, then you are going to need to override the MeasureOverride method on your control so you can throw a bunch of code at the problem of just what size your control should be in each situation.